# unable to rewrite url - PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link -

http://www.website.com/vendor.php/brand-name

Here brand name is dynamic and this works fine

But now I want to convert this link into

http://www.website.com/vendor/brand-name

when i try to access this - i get No input file specified.

I want to remove .php for only one file in my project -  vendor.php

and want to run it as

http://www.website.com/vendor/brand-name

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^vendor/brand-name$ /vendor.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vendor.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is brand-name a dynmic Path? and what happens when you type http://www.website.com/vendor/brand-name 
?

Comment: yes brand name is dynamic

Comment: So you want to remove the php extension from your url?

Comment: yes i want to remove .php

Comment: when i try to access
http://www.website.com/vendor/brand-name

i get
No input file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to vendor.php
RewriteRule . vebdor.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite "/vendor/foo" to "vendor.php/foo"
RewriteRule ^vendor/([^/]+)/?$ /vendor.php/$1 [NC,L]
#Rewrite to vendor.php?tag=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vendor.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I want to remove .php extension only for one file vendor.php

Comment: tried again , getting same  - No input file specified